# Program to calculate the time after 1250 hrs?

Tags: java, math, time, hour

In an interview he asked me a time question that I wasn't able to answer. Can someone help me to solve this question? He asked me to write a program in Java.

Question:-

> The time now is 11.30 PM. After 1250 hrs what is the time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about programming, it's about arithmetic.

Comment: `LocalTime.of(23, 30).plusHours(1250)`. Assuming that summer time (DST) doesn't start or end within those 1250 hours.

Comment: *He asked me to write a program in Java.* This question is about programming (but poorly researched and lacking an effort, so should maybe have been closed anyway).

Comment: @OleV.V. that bit about Java was added like almost 30 minutes *after* I voted to close.

Comment: @OleV.V. I voted to reopen, just because it was closed for the wrong reason, but the question is still a "give me the codez"-type one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this logic**

```
Total Hours : 1250
No of hours per day : 24
So 1250%24 = 2 hours (remainder)
```

*Result:* 11:30 pm + 2 hours = 1:30 am

Comment: This may or may not be true, depending on time zone.

Answer (score 1):

- After 24 hours, time is repeated.
- After 1250 hours = 52 * 24 hours + 2 hours.
- So the answer is 11:30pm + 2 hours = `1:30 AM`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Java Code
public Date addHoursToJavaUtilDate(Date date, int hours) {
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTime(date);
  calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1250 );
  return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Note that Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY is referring to a 24-hour clock.

More ref : https://www.baeldung.com/java-add-hours-date

```js
var today = new Date('01-01-2019 11:30 PM');
var dt =today.setHours(today.getHours() + 1250);
console.log(new Date(dt).toString());
```

Time would be 01:30 AM.

Comment: Also, I'm getting "invalid date"

Comment: javascript is just to explain the thing in a proper manner. I was hoping you like that

Comment: It's not that I don't like that, but maybe you could add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: 1250 hrs 
1 day is having 2 hrs So exclude all days
1250%24 = 2 hrs means
11:30 PM + 02  = 01:30 AM

Comment: In the answer, not in comments. Anyway, the question is now about Java, so you may want to re-write your answer in Java, make it language-agnostic or delete it.

Comment: The `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated, so not recommended. Use either `ZonedDateTime` (for more trustworthy results) or `LocalTime`.

Comment: Okay, Thanks to updating me.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes years ago with the adoption of JSR 310.